Why is heptadecane referred to as a solid if its melting point is below standard ambient temperature?
Heptadecane's melting point is $22^\circ $ and standard ambient temperature is $25^\circ$, but online I see that heptadecane is marked as a solid. Why is that?

You have omitted the context of data. Can the data be from the era when standard room/lab temperature was 20, before that 18, and before that even 15 deg C?

For that matter is Ga liquid or solid at "room temp"? With global warming, the answer changes...

It is more about heating up rooms and labs more and more. :-) Labs of old, genuine scientists were very cold.

Wikipedia says it is colorless liquid.

I heard a talk once from a Japanese chemist (speaking in the USA) who referred to a "room temperature reaction" that was carried out at 30 C. He made a joke about labs in Japan being hot, but I presume he used the higher temp to make his rates look better.

As commented by NilayGhosh, some sources say it's a liquid: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecane Please cite your source. // It's also worth noting that the reported melting T can be a range:  21.1 to 22.9 °C.

Ambient temperature is not always taken as 25°C. Sometimes 20°C is used; properties such as solubility are often reported at that temperature in Wikipedia articles on chemical compounds. Back in the 1970s it was recommended in the USA to reduce thermostats to 68°F = 20°C during heating season as an energy conservation measure (read: we needed to import less Middle Eastern oil). This may have popularized using 20°C.
,"Standard laboratory or industrial ambient temperature" is inevitably "driven by geography". The use of 20°C is documented in [Doiron[1]].
Reference

Doiron, Theodore D. (January 2007). "20 Degrees Celsius--A Short History of the Standard Reference Temperature for Industrial Dimensional Measurements". NIST. 112 (1): 1–23. doi:10.6028/jres.112.001. PMC 4654601. PMID 27110451.


I once had borrowed a (Czech) texbook of tabulated lab data, probably issued in 1970s or late 1960s. Many tables, mostly for solution densities, were for 15 deg C. some for 18 or 20, (almost?) none for 25.
